# automatic transpose of vectors for binary operations

Tags: matlab

I know there are alternatives exist. But just curious to know. When I perform some binary operations such as *,-,/,+ between two vectors of same size, some times the dimension does not match. For eg., for a*b a is of size (m,1) and b is also of size (m,1). or for a-b, the size of a,b is (m,1) and (1,m) respectively. Is there a way that matlab automatically matches dimension of vectors and performs the operation.

Comment: Be careful of the difference between `a*b` and `a.*b`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach is to use

```
a(:)-b(:)
```

instead of `a-b`. The linear indexing `(:)` turns everything into a column vector.

If one of the operands is in turn the result of an operation, for example `b+c`, you can't directly write `a(:)-(b+c)(:)` in Matlab. In that case you can use `reshape`, like this:

```
reshape(a,[],1) - reshape(b+c,[],1)
```

This works because `reshape(...,[],1)`, like `(:)`, converts its argument into a column; but now that argument can be the result of an operation.

Comment: how do you handle if b is also an outcome of binary operation. for eg., a+c*d, where the b=c*d. Ofcourse, we can say b=c*d and then still use a(:)+b(:). Is there another way of doing it. I tried a(:)+(c*d)(:). Matlab is throwing an error.

Comment: Define a little helper: `tocol=@(x)(x(:))` then use `a(:)+tocol(c*d)`

Comment: @RamakrishnanKannan You could use `reshape` in that case. I've updated my answer

Comment: @LuisMendo: Correct answer as always. :-) But maybe it is worth pointing out that the error message is not just an inconvenience but has a good reason since `*` implements matrix multiplication, and "automatic transpose" suggested in the question would mean introducing a bug.

Comment: @A.Donda Thanks! And good observation. The OP probably was referring to `.*`, for which automatic transposition would be more conceivable than it is for `*`